# How to simplify the search with an interval in an SQl query?

Tags: sql

Please tell me if it is somehow easier to write this query where the check occurs at intervals?

```
SELECT type, time_from, time_to 
FROM manager_orders 
WHERE aptid = 262707 
  AND cancelled_at is null 
  AND ('2021-04-26 11:00:00' 
       BETWEEN time_from - INTERVAL 30 Minute 
           AND time_to + INTERVAL 30 Minute
    OR '2021-04-26 11:00:00'
       BETWEEN time_from - INTERVAL 30 Minute
           AND time_to + INTERVAL 60 Minute
  )
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @TheImpaler, Yes, exactly, I corrected the request

Comment: It seems the second interval check covers entirely the first one. If that's the case there's no need to include the first one.

Comment: First member of OR  is redudant.